# Aplicação de Bootstrap em ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

Bom dia, tenho uma aplicação em ASP.NET Core 2 onde utilizo a ultima versão do Bootstrap(4.3.1), peguei alguns códigos na documentação mas quando coloco no meu HTML eles sempre aparecem sem o layout, apenas os textos como se o CSS não estivesse carregado

```html
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Principal</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="ConsultaCarros" asp-action="Index">Consulta carros</a>
                </li>
    
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container mt-3">
     <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-success class</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

O Panel não herda o CSS, como devo fazer?

Comment: Está aparecendo algum erro no console?

Comment: Não, não aparece erros

Comment: Testando apenas esse pedaço de código em um .html em branco funcionou normalmente....

Comment: Verifica se sua aplicação consegue baixar os arquivos de CSS (visualizando pelo Networking do navegador). Caso sim, tenta baixar os arquivos e colocar localmente dentro do projeto e faça as devidas alterações de caminhos. Também faça o teste de cache e veja se não pode está atrapalhando em nada. Testa e veja se funciona. Eu tive um problema parecido, porém o proxy bloqueava o download de alguns arquivos quando carregado por Link no head.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, o Panel foi substituido para Card na versão 4:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#panels

Segue exemplos de uso:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/